eas submit --platform ios failing due to icons not being found
i finished a small react native + expo app, i released the apk with no problems, im building the app with no errors with eas build, but with  eas submit --platform ios im getting the following error:

Something went wrong when submitting your app to Apple App Store Connect.
Your iOS app icon is missing or is an invalid format. The icon must be a 1024x1024 PNG image with no transparency.
Check your icon image and icon configuration in app.json.
Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/app-icons/

although the icon is 1024x1024 the path is correct and it is not transparent or have any transparent pixels
this is my app.json file:
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "PharmacyServiceDonations",
    "slug": "PharmacyServiceDonations",
    "version": "2.1.1",
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.anonymous.PharmacyServiceDonations",
      "icon": "./assets/icon/adaptive-icon.png",
      "buildNumber": "2.1.1"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.anonymous.PharmacyServiceDonations"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "58244e3c-69dd-4e9d-ac67-cffb4a705d19"
      }
    }
  }
}

and the info.plist:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>2.1.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconName</key>
    <string>AppIcon</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>SplashScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>arm64</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Your message to user when the camera is accessed for the first time</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Your message to user when the microphone is accessed for the first time</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Your message to user when the photo library is accessed for the first time</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Your message to user when the photo library is accessed for the first time</string>
</dict>
</plist>

